# Live HTML form validation (onBlur) in Angular, TypeScript

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am using Angular 7 with TS and I want to validate forms in frontend before sending a request to the backend.

I am using now fluent-ts-validator which seems to be a very useful library and can be used as a layer that validates the objects before the service sends the requests.

Now, I have this challenge to make a live validation which means, when a user blurs an HTML element, a validation (green check or red borders with a message when error) should be informed.

I can achieve that of course with many if/else and functions snippets. And my question would be if there is a better way to achieve that like a library or some sort of generic abstraction that can be connected with HTML forms?

Thanks

P.S. I am not limited to technologies or libraries. But I would love to stay focusing on Angular and TypeScript

Comment: Are you using reactive form ?

Comment: No, I am not! I have used them before, but I wasn't that happy actually because there are many codes should be written in HTML, especially if you have different error messages to the same HTML Input. I am trying to minimize my code as much as possible.

Comment: Besides, I don't want to lose the two-way binding in Angular.

Comment: IMO using reactive forms will keep your code and template clean and maintainable. Since you mention you have different errors for same fields. It would be better to create custom validator for them. This way the validator can return different errors based on various validation conditions. I presume in your template you are anyways checking for `fieldName.errors` to toggle error css classes. This also helps in separation of concern and testing.

Comment: Exactly, I will take Reactive forms into consideration. But I actually also thought to create a custom component that pop up or write a div with some design when an Error occurs. And it will get its Status from fluent-ts-validator. Because within the validator, the invalid property is also mentioned. So, I can in somehow inside this global component find the correct error message, if any! The idea is not complete in my mind and that is why I would love to share and hear thoughts. But I will reconsider using Reactive forms. What do you think?

Comment: I am not very familiar with fluent-ts-validator. Will soon share something once I go through it. Meanwhile, regarding the custom component creation that you mentioned. I would suggest to create an attribute directive that can wrap the host element and also monitor it for errors. This directive can depend on the formControlName to read the errors if used in a reactive form. Also it would help to normalize the error messages or error object model. The directive can define the error object interface which can be used by custom validators to return errors.

Comment: Ooh, that is nice! Thanks for the tip. I would definitely try to implement it.